# Adding a custom quicklist-entry to a .desktop file

Tags: gnome, firefox, launcher, touchscreen, gnome-shell

On my system, Firefox needs to be started with the option

```
MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox
```

in order to get my touchscreen to work with Firefox, while

```
MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox
```

seems to work fine too.

Now, I would like to add this starting option to the launcher. Ideally,

- `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox` should become the default option;
- `firefox %u` should become an additional quicklist-entry;
- The option (quicklist entry) to launch a new window should remain.
- The option (quicklist entry) to launch a private window should remain.
- The custom launcher should persist through Firefox updates.
- The quicklist toolstips should be multilanguage (english and german)

On my way trying to achieve these things, I fiddled with Alacarte and Menulibre; I modified `usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` 
I copied the modified `firefox.desktop` to `./local/share/applications/` in order to start Firefox from there. None of that worked, so I did a clean reinstall of Firefox and write this post. The system is Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME Shell 3.24.2

P.S. I am not sure if those tiny dark-grey boxes are called quicklist in gnome-shell. If not, what I mean is the equivalent of unity-quicklists in gnome-shell, where you can select to launch a new private window, for example.

Comment: Thsose grey boxes, well you could better call them `tooltips` or `quick-menus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all copying a `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` will make the copy overwrite the system wide icon only for you. Means you should in most cases not edit files put into `/usr/share/applications` copy it first and edit it then in `~/.local/share/applications`.

As for how to create such a desktop file for your needs, the contents should look like this:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Comment[de]=Im Internet surfen
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Keywords[de]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Webseite;Site;surfen;online;browsen
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1; firefox %u' 
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-window-wi;new-private-window;new-private-window-wi;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a new Window
Name[de]=Ein neues Fenster öffnen
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=0; firefox -new-window'

[Desktop Action new-window-wi]
Name=Open a new Touch-Window
Name[de]=Ein neues Touch-Fenster öffnen
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1; firefox -new-window'

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Name[de]=Ein neues privates Fenster öffnen
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=0; firefox -private-window'

[Desktop Action new-private-window-wi]
Name=Open a New Private Touch-Window
Name[de]=Ein neues privates Touch-Fenster öffnen
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1; firefox -private-window'
```

I left out the language specific strings, except the German ones, so it becomes more clear what needs to be changed.

You can simply make a new file in `~/.local/share/applications` by copying the above code field with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

and pasting in your previous copied code field with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. To exit editing then simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, confirm your write by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to write to the filename given.

Since an update will only overwrite the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` this edit should last through updates. but you need to confirm on major changes that the file is still correct according to the system wide file.

- [image: check] `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox` should become the default option;
- [image: check] The option (quicklist entry) to launch a new window should remain.
- [image: check] The option (quicklist entry) to launch a private window should remain.
- [image: check] The custom launcher should persist through Firefox updates.
- [image: check] The quicklist toolstips should be multilanguage (english and german)

Comment: Sorry to say, but somehow your solution did not work. I created ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop with touch and pasted your code in pluma. Firefox behaved like a fresh install, even after a reboot and replacing the starter in the gnome-shell. When copying the .desktop file with your code to /usr/share/applications and double klicking on it, an error message says "an error occured". Gnome-Shell does not find the browser anymore. (No worries I made a backup of the original file ;)  )

Comment: Can you provide a pastebin of the actual original file then so i can revise my answer according to it. I tested my solution in Ubuntu 17.10 and it did work.

Comment: Also you could try to put the `Exec` value lines in `"`. Example: `Exec="MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /usr/bin/firefox"`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bGfK1iz0 There is the paste, I will try  value lines.

Comment: That is exact an identical file where I started from and based my answer upon. I think leaving out the `%u` at the default is a bad move tho

Comment: And my other modified `.desktop` files are working without the `"`. Does the file work if you place it on the desktop? What you get when right clicking the icon there?

Comment: Leaving out the %u is probably bad, d'accord.  When placing your file on the desktop, i get an error message telling something like "starter for not-trusted applications ... the app starter is marked as not trustworthy ..." . It's the same as when clicking on any starter in ~/.local/share/applications/ , even starters that work when starting with gnome-shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69418/discussion-between-videonauth-and-johnnybegood).